# Trying to convert complex JSON to CSV with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and I am trying to convert this JSON file to CSV.

Using some simple code like this:

```
$sourceFilePath = "Records.json"
$destinationFilePath = "Records.csv"
((Get-Content -Path $sourceFilePath -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json) | Export-CSV $destinationFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

Results in:
[image]

Because I am getting System.Object[] I think I need to do some kind of expansion or "ForEach" of the contact_ids, site_ids, first name aliases, and aliases. I've done some searching and I can't seem to wrap my head around the examples I've been given. Also, "first name aliases" has spaces in it that add to the complexity.

I don't have any control over the source JSON. Here it is as an example:

```
[
  {
    "mdm id" : "947b2a12-3aac-480a-a0bf-626aff106f48",
    "first name" : "Claude",
    "last name" : "Bones",
    "contact_ids" : [
      "CTP70499"
    ],
    "site_ids" : [
      "5015"
    ],
    "first name aliases" : [
      "Claude"
    ],
    "aliases" : [
      "Claude Bones"
    ],
    "createdDate" : "2020-06-03T19:59:08Z",
    "updatedDate" : "2020-06-03T20:48:27Z",
    "veevaID" : "V0B000000000569"
  },
  {
    "mdm id" : "bce21b05-0b28-4ebb-a34d-761c1a397821",
    "first name" : "Daniel",
    "last name" : "Smith",
    "contact_ids" : [
      "CTP699"
    ],
    "site_ids" : [
      "5015"
    ],
    "first name aliases" : [
      "Dan",
      "Danial",
      "Danne",
      "Danny",
      "Daniel"
    ],
    "aliases" : [
      "Daniel Smith"
    ],
    "createdDate" : "2020-06-03T19:59:08Z",
    "updatedDate" : "2020-06-03T20:48:27Z",
    "veevaID" : "V0B000000000566"
  }
]
```

Comment: In the cases where there is more than one value per property, are you wanting to just have them joined with a comma?

Comment: @DougMaurer yes that would work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values that are arrays will need to be combined into a single value. Regardless of how many values it may have, if it's designated as an array `[]` in json, it will need to be manipulated. There are several articles and custom functions written on the internet. Your example could be handled with this bit of code.

```
$JSONdata = @'
[
  {
    "mdm id" : "947b2a12-3aac-480a-a0bf-626aff106f48",
    "first name" : "Claude",
    "last name" : "Bones",
    "contact_ids" : [
      "CTP70499"
    ],
    "site_ids" : [
      "5015"
    ],
    "first name aliases" : [
      "Claude"
    ],
    "aliases" : [
      "Claude Bones"
    ],
    "createdDate" : "2020-06-03T19:59:08Z",
    "updatedDate" : "2020-06-03T20:48:27Z",
    "veevaID" : "V0B000000000569"
  },
  {
    "mdm id" : "bce21b05-0b28-4ebb-a34d-761c1a397821",
    "first name" : "Daniel",
    "last name" : "Smith",
    "contact_ids" : [
      "CTP699"
    ],
    "site_ids" : [
      "5015"
    ],
    "first name aliases" : [
      "Dan",
      "Danial",
      "Danne",
      "Danny",
      "Daniel"
    ],
    "aliases" : [
      "Daniel Smith"
    ],
    "createdDate" : "2020-06-03T19:59:08Z",
    "updatedDate" : "2020-06-03T20:48:27Z",
    "veevaID" : "V0B000000000566"
  }
]
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$JSONdata | foreach {
    $record = [ordered]@{}
    foreach($property in $_.psobject.Properties)
    {
        if($property.value -is [string])
        {
            $record.Add($property.name,$property.value)
        }
        else
        {
            $record.Add($property.name,($property.value -join ', '))
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$record
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output

```
"mdm id","first name","last name","contact_ids","site_ids","first name aliases","aliases","createdDate","updatedDate","veevaID"
"947b2a12-3aac-480a-a0bf-626aff106f48","Claude","Bones","CTP70499","5015","Claude","Claude Bones","2020-06-03T19:59:08Z","2020-06-03T20:48:27Z","V0B000000000569"
"bce21b05-0b28-4ebb-a34d-761c1a397821","Daniel","Smith","CTP699","5015","Dan, Danial, Danne, Danny, Daniel","Daniel Smith","2020-06-03T19:59:08Z","2020-06-03T20:48:27Z","V0B000000000566"
```

Simply change it to `Export-Csv`